# Change VS2005 global key bindings

Tags: visual-studio

When VS2005 has been started for the first time the user is asked for a key-binding. The result can be that projects are built with "Ctrl-Shift-B" or "F7" depending on the answer. I have chosen the "default" with "Ctrl-Shift-B". Now I want to use the other way, since I use several other IDEs with "F7" for build. How can I answer this question again?

I already klicked on `Reset` in the Options/Keyboard Dialog without any success.

Comment: Do you really want to completely replace *every* keyboard shortcut?  Simply add the F7 key binding for just the Build.BuildSolution command.

Comment: F7 is currently used for another command (View.ToggleDesigner). It would be nice if I would find this command on the corresponding other key. But F7 is so in the fingertips that changing this one could help. Nevertheless I am interested to start over again.